# Loading trained model on embedded systems (No libraries)

Tags: machine-learning, embedded, artificial-intelligence

I'm not too familiar with Machine Learning techniques, and i want to know if I can transfer a final trained-model to another machine. More specifically, i'm trying to solve a sound classification problem by training a model on a regular PC, and then implement / transfer its output model to an embedded system where no libraries are allowed (C programming). The system does not support file reading either.

So my question is.

Are there learning methods with output models simple enough that it can be implemented easily on other systems? How would you implement it? (Something like Q-learning? although Q-learning wouldn't be appropriate in my project.)

I would like some pointers, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have "no libraries" what will process the model data?

Comment: the learning can be done in PC with any programming language or libraries. Its the embedded system part that has such restrictions

Comment: You have misunderstood - the model is just data, _something_ has to process that data - either you have written code to do that or you are using a library.  It is not magic - the model will not run itself!  Code is required to perform the classification, just as code is required to train the model.

Comment: yes and so i was thinking maybe the final model can be generated without any dependency, like a function or something. I think your answer below is what im looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any arbitrary "blob" of data can be converted into a C byte array and compled and linked directly with your code.  A code generator is simple enough to write, but there are tools that will do that directly such a [Segger Bin2C](https://www.segger.com/free-utilities/bin2c/) (and any number of other tools called "bin2c") or the swiss-army knife of embedded data converters [SRecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/).

Since SRecord can do so many things, getting it to do this one thing is less than obvious:

```
srec_cat mymodel.nn -binary -o model.c -C-Array model -INClude
```

will generate a model.c and model.h file defining a data array containing the byte content of mymodel.nn.